# Problems with vim-r

Tags: vim, tmux, r

Getting the following error when opening an .R file in vim (vim-r installed).

> Error detected while processing /home/johnros/.vim/r-plugin/common_global.vim:
>
> line 3106: E484: Can't open file /tmp/vIuKjzl/0
>
> line 3327: E484: Can't open file /tmp/vIuKjzl/1

I have also imported my .vim library and .vimrc from another PC where it works nicely, so I suspect it might have to do with my environment variables.

Running fish shell, but also tried on bash.

Any ideas?

Update:
When ssh'ing to a remote PC, if I tmux before ssh'ing, the problem persists. If I tmux after ssh'ing, there is no problem.
tmux on local machine is 1.9 and on remote 1.5. I thus suspect vim-r does not support  tmux>1.5

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem is with the shell. In particular, the screen plugin needed for vim-r cannot be sourced when fish is set to the default shell.

To solve this, chsh /bin/bash (or any other POSIX compatible shell).

P.S. running vim in non POSIX shells in general does seem like a very good idea. With great sorrow, I have abandoned fish shell and reverted to zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Add `set shell=/bin/bash` to the top of your `.vimrc`. Then you can use whatever shell you want but vim will use bash.